# Set lastrow variable as 3 lines offset from the last occupied row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set the variable lastrow. I want the value of it to be 3 rows less than the last occupied row of my excel sheet. To be more clear, my current last occupied row is row 50. But I want the lastrow variable to be set as 47.
My code so far.

```
lastrow1 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 3
```

Comment: And what isn't working? Are you using the right sheet and did you intend on using column A to find the last row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four things.

1. Ensure you are working with the expected workbook e.g. ThisWorkbook
2. Ensure ws2 is the sheet you intend to work with
3. Ensure column A is the column you want to use to find the last row
4. Check that the lastrow is >= 4 before attempting to remove 3.

   Code for check:

   ```
   lastRow1 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    
   lastRow1 = IIf(lastRow1 < 4, 1, lastRow1 - 3)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name of your sheet").Activate
    Dim cnt As Integer, lastrow As Double
    cnt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count  'Counts no of rows
    'Assuming that you want value in column A
    lastrow = Range("A" & cnt-3).Value
```